# How to pick the right motor driver?

Tags: arduino, motor, current

I have this brushed DC motor (Vex 775pro: https://motors.vex.com/vexpro-motors/775pro; motor curve data here I assume is useful but I do not exactly know how to make sense of it) My question is, how do I select a motor driver that can handle the current that my motor is drawing and how do I know how much current my motor is drawing?

I would like to purchase a standard H-bridge motor driver so I can control the speed and make the motor go clockwise or counterclockwise. Looking up some things online, I see that I should pick a motor driver that can provide current equal to or above the motor's continuous current consumption under load, however I am not sure what the "continuous current consumption under load" is for this motor. Also in case it matters for anything, I do plan on using this with an Arduino. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You might like to read my answer to a similar question: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/510755/help-with-choice-of-dc-motor-speed-control-pwm-vs-regulator Please feel free to ask me any newbie questions on motor driver.

Comment: Your link is broken. Do you mean this one? 775pro DC Motor US$20 - Vexrbotics
https://www.vexrobotics.com/775pro.html

Comment: VexRobotics 775Pro spec is summarized below: 12VDC, 0.71Nm, 347W, 5mm, 18,730 rpm, 700mA (stall 134A) . Are you sure you want 18,730 rpm? And stall 134A won't scare you away? Or are you going to gear it down?

Answer (score 1):

For every component you can search for data sheets over the respective manufacturer site. You can know the rated current of motor otherwise on the shopping site. Then find a motor driver for that rating. Or else you can design it on your own.